# Splash screen and icon falls back to the default when building my app with EAS build

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I have been faced with this issue and it is very frustrating.
Splash screen and icon falls back to the default when building my app with EAS build. The App icon and splash screen gets replaced by the default expo ones.

Here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "***************",
    "slug": "*************",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],


    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "nativeVersion"
    },

    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.chimaobi.AbP"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "***************"
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: same issue. How did you resolve it ?